# retrieving words from a single line in a file using fgets and strtok

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I have the functions below which reads words from a file and outputs each word using fgets and strtok where the words in the file are split by newline:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

I'm trying to mimic the functionality where the words in the file are on a single line split only by a space:

```
word1 word2 word3
```

However I seem to only be able to get the first word whilst changing the strtok char to " " and attempting to read a single line. I'm unsure what i'm missing.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int readLines;
char *output[255];
char *filename = "commands.txt";

char fileRead(const char *filename, char *output[255])
{
  int count = 0;
  char input[255];
  char *line;
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file: %s\n", filename);
  } else {
    while(count < 255 && fgets(input, sizeof(input), file)) {
      line = strtok(input, "\n");
      if (line) {
        output[count++] = strdup(line); /* Store replica */
      }
    }
    fclose(file);
  }
  return count;
}

char *strdup(const char *str)
{
  char *ret = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
  if (ret) {
    strcpy(ret, str);
  }
  return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  readLines = fileRead(filename, output);
  /* read from array and pass into flag function */
  for (int x = 0; x < readLines; ++x) {
    printf("%s\n", output[x]);
    free(output[x]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to loop on `strtok()`.  The first call will supply `input` as the first argument to `strtok()`; the subsequent ones `NULL`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer ah that's right thank you

Comment: an error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a system function, should use `perror()` which will both output the enclosed text AND the appropriate system error message.  Usually the best thing to do is call `exit()` after displaying the message rather than allowing the program to continue

Comment: it is poor programming practice to have a local function those name (and overall signature) is the same as a system function.  Note that `strdup()` is a system function exposed when the header file `string.h` is included

Comment: the posted code has a massive memory leak.  (or, to put it differently, the code should always cleanup after itself.) The code should be calling `free()` for each of the char arrays obtained via `strdup()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question -- that you want to separate words (*tokens*) that are all contained on one line in a file, then you are using `strtok` incorrectly. In your code you have `line = strtok(input, "\n");` where the *delimiter* is the *newline*. If you want to separate *space* separated words, then you need a `space` included in your delimiter as well, e.g. `char *delim = " \n";`

Further, on the first call to `strtok` you use the variable name of the buffer (or pointer to the buffer) holding the text you want to tokenize. For all remaining calls to `strtok` (e.g. for words `2, 3, 4...`) you use `NULL` in its place and check the return.

Boiling your example down, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 255

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "",
        *delim = " \n";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {  /* read one line from file */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file read failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* tokenize line with strtok */
    for (char *p = strtok (buf, delim); p; p = strtok (NULL, delim))
        printf ("%s\n", p);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/strtok.dat
my dog has fleas
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtokoneline <dat/strtok.dat
my
dog
has
fleas
```

If I misunderstood, then drop a comment and I'm happy to help further. If you have any other questions about the answer, just ask.

If you prefer writing your `strtok` loop as a `while` loop instead of a `for` (it can be easier to look at), you can do something like the following:

```
    char buf[MAXC] = "",
        *p = buf,
        *delim = " \n";
    ...
    p = strtok (buf, delim);        /* get first token (word) */

    while (p) {
        printf ("%s\n", p);
        p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* get remaining tokens */
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David, you are correct I was missing that loop. The while is indeed cleaner as well, thank you.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Also, always remember that while library tools like `strtok`, `strsep`, and `sscanf` can help you parse/split and tokenize, there is nothing that you cannot parse or separate simply by *walking a pointer* (or pair of pointers) *down the string* and checking each character as you go. For complex parsing, sometimes it is the best way to go. (you can simply search *"walk a pointer"* and find numerous examples on S.O.) Use the library functions, but if they won't work -- a pointer and `if` statements will `:)` Good luck with your coding.